# Cannot access $el of Vue component except on $mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, vue-component

Trying to loop through an array of Vue components and access the DOM element of each component. This seems like a fairly basic need, but I've searched a lot and although there are plenty of questions in the same general area, I have not come up with a solution to this one.

Context: my app will access the DOM element to style text according to app logic. For this post, I've created a cut-down, minimal app to reproduce my issue, so it doesn't do any styling but simply displays the innerText of the element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5xb1v0e/) or see same code below. You'll see that this code succeeds in accessing the component's `$el` briefly, within the $mounted event handler only. After that it's undefined. I could save a reference in the event handler, but it seems crazy to think that would be necessary... what am I missing?

HTML

```
<div id="app"
   oncontextmenu="return false" 
   v-on:mouseup="showchars()"
>
  <h2>The components a, b and c will be here once mounted. Note in the initial dialogs that their $el is accessible when their mount event handler calls showchars. Then click this div to call showchars again, and note that $el is no longer defined.</h2>
  <charcomponent 
    v-for = "c in charcomponents"
    v-bind:char="c.char"
   ></charcomponent>
</div>
```

JS

```
let CharComponent = {
    props: ['char'],
    mounted: function() {
      this.showinfo("it's like this on mount");
    },
    methods: {
      showinfo: function(cmt) {
        try {
          alert(cmt + ': char=' + this.char +', el=' + this.$el + ', and...');
          alert('...el.innerText=' + this.$el.innerText);
        }
        catch(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
      }  
    },
  template: '<p>{{ char }}</p>'  
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    charcomponent: CharComponent
   },
  data: {
    charcomponents: []
  },
  methods: {
    showchars() {
      for (var c of this.charcomponents) {
        c.showinfo("it's different later");      
      }
    }
  }
})

var ccharcomp = Vue.extend(CharComponent);

for (var ch of ['a','b','c']) {
    var ocharcomp = new ccharcomp({
    propsData: {
        char: ch
    }
  });
  vm.charcomponents.push(ocharcomp);
}
//alert(vm.chars.length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can try to explain what is happening, though I'm somewhat unclear why you're doing what you're doing.

Let's start here:

```js
var ocharcomp = new ccharcomp({
  propsData: {
    char: ch
  }
});
vm.charcomponents.push(ocharcomp);
```

This is creating new instances of the `ccharcomp` component, which is effectively just `CharComponent`. Each of these is then being added to the array.

None of these Vue instance is being mounted. They never get rendered. They are just created and pushed onto an array. They won't have an `$el` and the `mounted` hook will never be called.

Then in your template you have this:

```html
<charcomponent 
  v-for = "c in charcomponents"
  v-bind:char="c.char"
></charcomponent>
```

This loops over that same array and creates a new `CharComponent` instance for each entry. The value of `char` is copied across from each component in the array to the corresponding component created in the template.

The components created within the template will be rendered, mounted and will have an `$el`. It is this that you are seeing in your logging from the `mounted` hook.

Then we have this:

```js
showchars() {
  for (var c of this.charcomponents) {
    c.showinfo("it's different later");      
  }
}
```

This is looping over the original array of components, the ones that were never mounted. These don't have an `$el`, they never have. The components created by the template still exist and still have an `$el` but they are not in the array.

I can't make a concrete suggestion for how to fix your problem as I don't really understand why you are creating the child components in such a strange way. The more normal pattern would be:

1. Have the array `['a','b','c']` in the `data` for the relevant parent component.
2. Loop over that array in the template to create the children.
3. Use `ref` in the template and `$refs` in the parent to access the child components, then use `$el` to grab the element for each child.

However, if you just want to apply styling then grabbing the element like this is generally discouraged. Instead you should use `:class` or `:style` bindings within the template to let Vue apply the styling for you. You may need to introduce extra `data` properties to hold the underlying state so that the template can determine which styles to apply where.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I'm sure this is the explanation. btw I did try attribute bindings in the template, but found that unlike other template contents, these were not reactive, which defeated the purpose. I may revisit that approach but don't want to give up on this one yet as it seems looping through a known array of components would be useful generally, not just for this app. I also looked at using refs but that seems to add an extra stage of working out which child elements are of interest. Could you show how your step 3 would work?

Answer (score 1):

The components you are instantiating via this method (declarative):

```
<charcomponent 
  v-for = "c in charcomponents"
  v-bind:char="c.char"
></charcomponent>
```

Are different from the ones that you are creating here (programmatic):

```
var ccharcomp = Vue.extend(CharComponent);

for (var ch of ['a','b','c']) {
    var ocharcomp = new ccharcomp({
    propsData: {
        char: ch
    }
  });
  vm.charcomponents.push(ocharcomp);
}
```

The initial series of alerts were triggered by the mounted hook from for the first set of components (declarative). Definitely, the $el object is present here because of the markup is already part of the DOM and that it also used the local declaration that you have in your Vue instance

```
 components: {
    charcomponent: CharComponent 
   },
```

For the second set of components, which was stored in array named charcomponents, does not have any mounted elements. Take note you when you are using Vue.extend, only a subclass of the Vue instance is created and therefore new objects from instanciated must be mounted via the $mount method.

```
showchars() {
      for (var c of this.charcomponents) {
        c.showinfo("it's different later");      
      }
    }
```

Effectively, accessing the $el element for the second batch of components, it is not yet defined.

I create a simple implementation [here in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecnop04/6uyw2mac/52/) to show the different implementations.

Comment: I'm sure this is the explanation, as @skirtle has said, and your fiddle helps too as you've shown a way to mount the dynamic components as I create them, which I'm going to need if I stick with this approach. As it's a dynamic array, I still need to get my head around how to keep the relationship simple and clear between a known array of components and their DOM elements, which seems like a pretty basic thing to do.

Comment: You may want to consider using features like <component> and <slot>. This can give you some flexibility with mapping dynamic components in your DOM as well as rendering contents that need not be part of your component template.

Comment: Yeah was looking at slots yesterday. I think I can get everything I need into the template now, but it seems to me that even if the template gets all its data from binding, still there will be times when it is app logic that determines the value of whatever the template is bound to, and consequently a need to loop through a known list of components as I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

The very informative answers from @skirtle and @Jose Mari Ponce helped me to see why what I had wasn't working. I intend to look again at class/style binding in the template as a possibly better way of accomplishing what this particular app needs, but I wanted to follow this through too as it seems looping through a known list of components and accessing $el will also be needed, since app logic needs to determine the values the template is bound to. I also think it's something with much wider applicability beyond this one app.

It turned out to be simply a matter of replacing my HTML `v-for` with a JS `appendChild`, plus mounting the dynamically created component on the new child element:

HTML

```
<div id="components">
</div>
```

JS

```
var ccharcomp = Vue.extend(CharComponent);
var container = document.getElementById("components");

for (var ch of ['a','b','c']) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    container.appendChild(p);
    var ocharcomp = new ccharcomp({
        propsData: {
            char: ch
        }
    });
    vm.charcomponents.push(ocharcomp.$mount(p));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lyqph2/)